# How do I move my servers to a datacenter?

Tags: hosting, migration, colocation

I feel like an idiot for having to ask this, but essentially, I have a few server in my private data centre that I would like to repurpose for web hosting. I am currently hosting my site with goDaddy and after moving my servers to colocated hosting, I'm not sure how to assign domains from godaddy over to my servers. Also, I'll need to host multiple sites from each server so how will I go about doing that from a technical level?

Do I need to use a static IP on my servers?
Do I purchase that from my colocation provider?
How do I make sure that www.mysite1.com and www.mysitetwo.com both redirect to the same server but different sites?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would typically obtain static IP addresses from your colocation provider.  They may offer it at no charge.

You will need to configure the authoritative DNS servers for your domains to point to the new IP address(es).

Different domain names can be served by the same IP address using a technique known as virtual hosts.  Configuration varies depending upon your web server software.